# How do I understand linebreaks in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, newline

I have a piece of XML that looks like:

```
<bunch of other things>
<bunch of other things>
<errorLog> error1 \n error2 \n error3 </errorLog>
```

I want to modify the XSLT that this XML runs through to apply newlines after `errors1` through `error3`.

I can completely control the output of errorLog or the contents of the XSLT file, but I'm not sure how to craft either the XML or the XSLT to make the output HTML show line breaks. Is it easier to change the XML output into some special character that will cause a newline, or do I modify the XSLT to interpret `\n` as newlines?

There is an [example on this site](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/01/03/preserving-line-breaks-in-XML-while-transforming-to-html-with-XSLTt/) that contains something akin to what I want, but my `<errorLog>` XSLT is nested in another template, and I'm not sure how templates inside templates can work.

Comment: Templates don't nest.  Show what your xsl looks like currently.

Answer (score 3):

Backslash is used as an escape character in a number of languages including C and Java, but not in XML or XSLT. If you put \n in your stylesheet, that's not a newline, it's two characters backslash followed by "n". The XML way of writing a newline is `&#xa;`. However, if you send a newline to the browser in HTML, it displays it as a space. If you want a newline displayed by the browser, you need to send a `<br/>` element.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over your `errorLog` element then you may as well use a literal LF character in there. It is no different from any other character as far as XSLT is concerned.

As for creating HTML that displays with line breaks, you will want to add a `<br/>` element in place of whatever marker you have in your XML source. It would be easiest of all if you could put each error within a separate element, like this

```
<errorLog>
  <error>error1</error>
  <error>error2</error>
  <error>error3</error>
</errorLog>
```

then the XSLT doesn't have to go through the rather clumsy process of splitting up the text itself.

With this XML data taken from your question

```
<document>
  <bunch-of-other-things/>
  <bunch-of-other-things/>
  <errorLog>error1 \n error2 \n error3</errorLog>
</document>
```

this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/document">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Error Log</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="errorLog">
    <p>
      <xsl:call-template name="split-on-newline">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="split-on-newline">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($string, '\n')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, '\n')"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:call-template name="split-on-newline">
          <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '\n')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        <br/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce this output

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Error Log</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <bunch-of-other-things/>
      <bunch-of-other-things/>
      <p>error1 <br/> error2 <br/> error3<br/>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That makes a ton of sense. I can make each error inside it's own error element like in your first example.

Once that is done, how should I change the xsl to create newlines between each error element?